# used to - why present tense?

Tags: tradução-inglês, tempo-verbal

This is from a Portuguese lesson/review on Duolingo. I am beginning to doubt that they had the right translation.

The phrasal use of the verb *use* in "used to" indicates a habit, in this case a habit in a past sense. It refers to a habit once kept, and is in past tense in English.

Is there a reason why in Portuguese you would use the present tense of *costumar* instead of the past tense? i.e, why is it:

> Nós nunca costumamos caminhar nessa rua.

instead of

> Nós nunca costumávamos caminhar nessa rua.

for

> We never used to walk on that street.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's likely not the present tense: [*nós costumamos*](http://www.conjuga-me.net/verbo-costumar) is present indicative and also *pretérito perfeito*. The *pretérito perfeito* in Portugal is *costumámos* or *costumamos*; in Brazil, *costumamos* only. *Nós costumávamos* is *pretérito imperfeito*. That said, the *pretérito perfeito* is not idiomatic for this purpose.

To say that you used to do something in some period in the past, the *imperfeito* is what you want:

> Nós não costumávamos caminhar naquela rua (naqueles tempos). [We didn’t use to walk on that street (in those days).]

To say that you never used to do something, that is, in no period in your whole life have you had a particular habit, the *pretérito perfeito* could be used, but it’s not idiomatic. It’s better to use *ter o costume/hábito de*:

> Nunca tivemos o costume de caminhar nessa rua. [We never had the habit of walking on that street.]

Note that *costumar* means to have a habit only. You don’t use it for things such as hating cabbage, dating someone, having a job, etc. In those cases you use the *imperfeito* of the main verb:

> Eu detestava couves quando era criança, mas agora até gosto. [I used to hate cabbage when I was a child, but now I like it; not *eu costumava detestar couves*.]
>
> Eu trabalhava em Lisboa nesses tempos. [I used to work in Lisbon in those days.]

Answer (score 5):

Em minha opinião, **nenhuma** dessas traduções é muito feliz.

A perífrase *costumar + verbo* exprime geralmente um valor de [aspeto habitual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_aspect), embora nem sempre, [como mostra Oliveira](http://www.ufjf.br/revistaveredas/files/2010/08/ARTIGO-8.pdf) com a frase «eu costumava ter uma amiga com inúmeras pulseiras. Ela parou quando começou a deformar o braço». A frase não será porventura muito elegante,  mas também não a rejeitaria (o mesmo se aplica àquela que o Jacinto dá como inaceitável: «eu costumava detestar couves»). Este uso não habitual aplica-se com muito mais força ao inglês *used to* (Oliveira cita o exemplo *the Temple of Diana used to stand at Ephesus*). Outro exemplo: *you didn't use to be this way* deve traduzir-se por *não eras assim*, embora não me pareça impossível *não costumavas ser assim*.

Em todo o caso, nas tuas frases há um estado habitual e um verbo que descreve geralmente um processo. Na seguinte frase (repara que substituí *nunca* por *não*):

> Não costumamos caminhar nessa rua.

temos duas interpretações: como pretérito perfeito (=*caminhámos* em Portugal) e como presente.

Como presente, a forma é perfeitamente aceitável, mas refere-se a um estado de coisas presente; uma frase semelhante é:

> Não caminhamos geralmente nessa rua.

Retirando o *geralmente*, temos ainda uma leitura habitual, mas que não admite as caminhadas excecionais que as frases com *costumar* admitem.

Mas claramente a frase original em inglês não descreve um estado presente. Consideremos a possibilidade de ser um pretérito perfeito, equivalente (em Portugal) a:

> Não costumámos caminhar nessa rua.

Pesquisando no [corpusdoportugues.org](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/), encontramos exatamente zero exemplos relevantes para `[costumar].[vJ*]` (*costumar* no pretérito perfeito); no CETEMPúblico temos apenas um exemplo para a pesquisa equivalente `[lema="costumar" & temcagr="PS_IND"]`:

> Numa relação de forças menos óbvia, com soberanias a respeitar, escolheu-se o que **costumámos** designar de «via lenta» de introdução de uma moeda única [...]

Parece-me que é um erro e que o autor queria escrever *costumamos designar*.

Portanto praticamente inexistem ocorrências de *costumar* no pretérito perfeito. Este ocorre quase sempre no pretérito imperfeito (*costumávamos*), o que é de esperar, dado que o pretérito imperfeito tem, tal como o presente, leituras habituais (*Quando havia sol, caminhávamos nessa rua*).

A razão por que a frase

> ??Nunca costumávamos caminhar nessa rua.

me parece pouco admissível deve-se à presença de *nunca*, que entra em conflito com *costumávamos*. *Nunca* é demasiado categórico para usar com *costumávamos*; o último deixa espaço para exceções. Repare-se também na impossibilidade/marginalidade duas frases seguintes:

> *Nunca caminhávamos geralmente nessa rua.
>   ??Geralmente, nunca caminhávamos nessa rua.

Se quisermos dizer *nunca teve o hábito de* (significado que é algo diferente), então temos de escrever:

> Nunca tivemos o hábito de caminhar naquela rua.

Uma pesquisa nos *corpora* confirma a raridade da combinação de *nunca* com *costumar*. Fazendo uma pesquisa por `"nunca" [lema="costumar.*"]` no [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=CETEMPUBLICO), temos zero resultados e apenas dois com a pesquisa correspondente no [corpusdoportugues.org](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/).

Comment: thank you, this was a great write up, and actually touched on some of my own thoughts on the issue.